# Maximum damage for Varus 's Q arrow

Tags: league-of-legends

I have a question on Varus champion on his Q ability.

At max arrow range after we hit Q the first time, we have 2-3 seconds more to wait for the spell to go off.

My question is during that wait for the second Q hit, does the arrow damage increase i.e. the later we hit Q the more damage it is?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer NamGVU Don't get into edit wars with each other. Additionally  we've allowed class and character specific tags for other games (like TF2) so it's entirely possible that we could start making them for LoL as well. However, that's a discussion that should be had in meta, not comments. Also, remember to [Be Nice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [ability description](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Varus),

> Varus channels for up to 4 seconds, increasing Piercing Arrow's range and damage over the next 2 seconds.

So you only gain damage while you are charging the ability to a cap after 2 seconds of channeling.

Comment: I didn't ask for the time it is flying :D

Comment: @NamGVU ah, I misread you question then. did I give you the info you were looking for though?

Comment: So Varus Q only gain more damage during the first 2-seconds of its 4-seconds channeling, right?

Comment: @NamGVU correct. the extra two seconds of channeling will not increase its damage or range